# Multiple domain server mail

Tags: ssl, domain, courier-imap

I have the following configuration :

- `domain1.com` -> `1.1.1.1`
- `domain2.com` -> `1.1.1.1`
- `domain3.com` -> `1.1.1.1`

They all point to the same machine and the same VHost / machine.
This machine has a `courier-imap[-ssl]` configured.

Each domain has email addresses.

The problem is I have a ssl certificate for `www.domain1.com`.
But when I configure an email address in my mail client for exemple contact@domain2.com wireshark tells me that the mail client is connecting to :

- `autodiscover.domain2.com` no big-deal cos not found in the dns record
- `domain2.com` using port 443 and has a certificate host address missmatch because my certificate is configured for domain1.com so my mail client raise an error and so are the customers.

My question is what is the correct way to handle this situation? To not get an ssl domain missmatch error. I want my customer to use imap.domain1.com as the incoming mail server. and smtp.domain1.com as the outgoing one. Without having the warning...

I tried to disable port 443 listening for domain2, domain3 etc ... but i can't find a way to do it apache is always handling it. Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution it's not the most elegant one but it works.

I put all the traffic off domain1.com on another ip and listen on apache Vhost only for this IP.
So when the mail client try to access https://domain2.com he has no result so no certificate missmatch and can then configure his imap and smtp manually

Answer (score 1):

That is what the autodiscover mechanism is for.

I assume use Outlook. You have to set up the subdomain and provide an autodiscover.xml. [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/kristinw/archive/2013/04/19/controlling-outlook-autodiscover-behavior.aspx) are some tips for that.

For other clients there can be other ways. Thunderbird for example uses autoconfig instead.

Comment: But everywhere i read the autodiscover is a function of EXCHANGE i don't have an exchange server.

Comment: As far as I know this is just a xml based format

Comment: I can't make an autodiscover file because the client mail is trying to access it with HTTPS and i don't have a certificate for other domains.

Comment: you could use a free certificate from startssl.com